# Show that there is a unique function on the interval that solves:

Tags: banach-spaces, integral-equations

$$f(x) = e^{-2x} + \int_0^\infty e^{-2x-2y} \sin(x-y)f(y) \, dy$$

I can't get a good bound on $e^{-2x-2y} \sin(x-y)$ so that I can apply Banach.

Comment: You shouldn't keep alternating into and out of MathJax in the course one line that contains only mathematical notation, and the "equals" and "plus" signs should be within MathJax, not outside of it.  Also, notice that a\sin b is rendered as $a\sin b$, with proper spacing and $\sin$ not italicized. $\qquad$

Comment: How did you get the bounds? Is it because $e^{ax}$ > $ae^x$?

Comment: What's the interval?

Answer (score 1):

Define the operator $T$ on an admissable class of functions (I'll use $V = \{ f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R : f \text{ is continuous and bounded} \}$ which is a Banach space with the supremum norm, $\|\cdot\|_\infty$) by $$(Tf)(x) =  e^{-2x} + \int^\infty_0 e^{-2x-2y} \sin(x-y) f(y) dy, \,\,\,\,\, x \ge 0.$$ Then for $f,g \in V$, $x \in [0\infty)$, $$\lvert (Tf)(x) - (Tg)(x) \rvert \le \int^\infty_0 e^{-2x} e^{-2y} \lvert \sin(x-y)\rvert \lvert f(y) - g(y)\rvert  dy.$$ But $e^{-2x} \le 1, \lvert \sin(x-y) \rvert \le 1$ and $\lvert f(y) - g(y) \rvert \le \| f - g\|_\infty$. Thus $$\lvert (Tf)(x) - (Tg)(x) \rvert \le \| f- g\|_\infty \int^\infty_{0} e^{-2x} dx = \frac{1}{2} \|f - g\|_\infty.$$ Since this holds for all $x$, we can pass to the supremum to see $$\|Tf - Tg \| \le \frac{1}{2} \| f - g\|_\infty.$$ This shows that $T$ is a contraction. It is straight-forward to show that $Tf \in V$ whenever $f \in V$; that is $T$ maps $V$ to $V$ (indeed, proving this uses basically the same steps used above to prove that $T$ is a contraction). So the Banach Fixed Point theorem gives existence of a fixed point.